# Pulling numeric and date values from excel file using C#

Tags: c#, excel

What is the correct protocol to get a date or numeric value out of an excel spreadsheet.  I have date values inside of an excel spreadsheet.  For instance, One column has 5/10/1973
When I add a watch to what is being pulled back using this code...

```
     wkSheet.get_Range("E" + row, "E" + row).Value2
```

The value that is returned is 26794.0?

Obviously, that is not what I am looking for.  So how do I properly get the value out of an excel spreadsheet.  I will continue to look for an answer to this, and hopefully I will be answering my own question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhah!

```
  wkSheet.get_Range("E" + row, "E" + row).Text
```

Gives you back the actual string that the user see.  You can then parse using

```
DateTime.Parse(string)
```

Thanks for the help fellow stack overflow users!